# d3js bars not updating properly

Tags: d3.js

I created this bars with a tooltip. I need to get them update after the `$('.quarter-increase, .quarter-decrease').on('click', function() {`

I don't get any errors but nothing gets updated...

```
      $(document).ready(function() {

    $('#prof-rendi').click(function() {
      $('.graph-loading').show();
      $('#svg-quarter').empty();
      var tooltip = tooltipd3();

      var svg = d3.select("svg#svg-quarter"),
        margin = {
          top: 20,
          right: 20,
          bottom: 30,
          left: 40
        },
        width = +svg.attr("width") - margin.left - margin.right,
        height = +svg.attr("height") - margin.top - margin.bottom;

      var x = d3.scaleBand().rangeRound([0, width]).padding(0.1),
        y = d3.scaleLinear().rangeRound([height, 0]);

      var g = svg.append("g").attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

      var div = d3.select("#svg-quarter").append("div"). // declare the tooltip div
      attr("class", "tooltip"). // apply the 'tooltip' class
      style("opacity", 0);

      d3.csv(base_url() + 'graph/getStatementsQuarterly/', function(d) {
        $('.graph-loading').hide();
        d.guadagno = +d.guadagno;
        return d;
      }, function(error, data) {
        if (error) 
          throw error;

        x.domain(data.map(function(d) {
          return d.periodo;
        }));
        y.domain([
          0,
          d3.max(data, function(d) {
            return d.guadagno;
          })
        ]);

        g.append("g").attr("class", "axis axis--x").attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")").call(d3.axisBottom(x));

        g.append("g").attr("class", "axis axis--y").call(d3.axisLeft(y).ticks(10)).append("text").attr("transform", "rotate(-90)").attr("y", 6).attr("dy", "0.71em").attr("text-anchor", "end").text("Guadagno")

        g.selectAll(".bar").data(data).enter().append("rect").attr("class", "bar").attr("x", function(d) {
          return x(d.periodo);
        }).attr("y", function(d) {
          return y(d.guadagno);
        }).attr("width", x.bandwidth()).attr("height", function(d) {
          return height - y(d.guadagno);
        }).on('mouseover', function(d) {
          var html = '<h5>' + d.guadagno + ' €</h5>';
          tooltip.mouseover(html); // pass html content
        }).on('mousemove', tooltip.mousemove).on('mouseout', tooltip.mouseout);
      });
    });

    $('.quarter-increase, .quarter-decrease').on('click', function() {
      $('.rendi-btn.left, .rendi-btn.right').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
      var where_at = $('#scroll-statement-quarter').val();
      $('.graph-loading').show();
      $('#svg-quarter').css({'opacity': 0.4});

      var tooltip = tooltipd3();

      var svg = d3.select("svg#svg-quarter"),
        margin = {
          top: 20,
          right: 20,
          bottom: 30,
          left: 40
        },
        width = +svg.attr("width") - margin.left - margin.right,
        height = +svg.attr("height") - margin.top - margin.bottom;

      var x = d3.scaleBand().rangeRound([0, width]).padding(0.1),
        y = d3.scaleLinear().rangeRound([height, 0]);

      var g = svg.append("g").attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

      var div = d3.select("#svg-quarter").append("div"). // declare the tooltip div
      attr("class", "tooltip"). // apply the 'tooltip' class
      style("opacity", 0);

      var speed = 500;

      d3.csv(base_url() + 'graph/getStatementsQuarterly/' + where_at, function(d) {
        $('.graph-loading').hide();
        d.guadagno = +d.guadagno;
        return d;
      }, function(error, data) {
        if (error) 
          throw error;

        x.domain(data.map(function(d) {
          return d.periodo;
        }));
        y.domain([
          0,
          d3.max(data, function(d) {
            return d.guadagno;
          })
        ]);

        g.append("g").attr("class", "axis axis--x").attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")").call(d3.axisBottom(x));

        g.append("g").attr("class", "axis axis--y").call(d3.axisLeft(y).ticks(10)).append("text").attr("transform", "rotate(-90)").attr("y", 6).attr("dy", "0.71em").attr("text-anchor", "end").text("Guadagno")

        g.selectAll(".bar").data(data).transition().duration(speed).attr("class", "bar").attr("x", function(d) {
          return x(d.periodo);
        }).attr("y", function(d) {
          return y(d.guadagno);
        }).attr("width", x.bandwidth()).attr("height", function(d) {
          return height - y(d.guadagno);
        }).on('mouseover', function(d) {
          var html = '<h5>' + d.guadagno + ' €</h5>';
          tooltip.mouseover(html); // pass html content
        }).on('mousemove', tooltip.mousemove).on('mouseout', tooltip.mouseout);
      });
    })
  });
```

This is a Plunker to test this:
https://plnkr.co/edit/72GCWqkllMFXZI6mecQE?p=preview

Press "show", then change the year to 2016 and you will see the result.

Comment: @GerardoFurtado ok fixed indentation. As for now jQuery is the only chance I have. The csv is async, yes, but it does work (changes the y values but does not update the bars)

Comment: Well, in that case, the best idea is creating a plunker/jsfiddle/codepen/whatever with that code and the corresponding CSVs.

Comment: @GerardoFurtado you are right. I placed a Plunker, pls see my update. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `g` variable inside the click event handler is a newly appended `<group>` element.

Therefore, this...

```
g.selectAll(".bar").data(data).etc...
```

... won't work, because there is nothing with a class `.bar` inside that group.

Solution: use the `svg` variable to select the rectangles:

```
svg.selectAll(".bar").data(data).etc...
```

Here is the updated plunker: https://plnkr.co/edit/eNa6Af0WcyrcLejadO2q?p=preview

PS: this code has *several* problems. I strongly advise you to not mix jQuery and D3, and also to not use `d3.csv` inside an event handler.

Comment: This is great. Tks for the advice. How would you do to call a different csv, with plain JS? There is still a problem with the scale and the bars update only once (if you go back to 2017 it doesn't work)

Comment: Please, since those are different problems, post another question.